# What's the best way to illustrate a web application software architecture (that uses Angular)?

Tags: web-applications, architecture, angularjs

We're developing a web application (using angular and .net web API) and we need a good way to illustrate our systems architecture.

I have a hard time grasping how to illustrate it.

As one might easily spot, I have a low level of experience on modeling and system architecture, and need some pointers to what to include and exclude, and how to illustrate it.

How do one best illustrate a systems architecture that incorporates angular, directives, services and external libraries etc?

My best approach so far:
[image: My best approach illustrating the architecture so far]

Comment: I am assuming that you have not yet implemented anything.. Do you already know what are the directives / services / libraries you need?

Comment: We have not implemented anything mentionworthy yet, and no we're not quite sure about the dependancies. But we're most interested in a generic approach anyways, so it shouldn't have an big impact.

Answer (score 2):

I forget where I originally saw/found this (I'm pretty sure it is/was on the Angular website somewhere), but it may give you some ideas.  External libraries could be another rectangle, or you might choose to wrap each in a service.

[image]